# Angular | Which is the better place to place logic, child or parent component?

Tags: javascript, angular

Consider that there is some re-usable component A with some logic(ex: an API call) which has to be performed on click of a button. A is used in two components B & C(not related to each other).

Now which is better among the following, in handling the logic?

1. Put conditions inside A's click function, depending on params passed as input from B's or C's call respective API.
2. Emit the event and write logic inside the B and C components separately.

Comment: Emit the event and write the logic in services injected in B and C components

Comment: Okay thanks, also may I know why it is better approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A being a re-usable component, it's a good practice to make it dumb : it should only communicate with inputs and outputs :
- inputs to get data from a parent component
- outputs to emit an event without caring about what will be done with the event

This way you make sure you can reuse your component in different situations without being heavily coupled with the potential parent : if you have a D component someday, you won't have to change the A component.

The parent is smart, with a given context. But it doesn't mean it should carry all the logic. In order to separate the concern of each file, it's better to put the logic inside a service (and it'll be easier to test without being coupled to a component)